# What is a sprite in papervision 3D?

Tags: 3d, papervision3d

What is a sprite in papervision 3D?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Do you mean a [Sprite3D](http://www.paultondeur.com/2008/07/03/papervision3d-sprite3d-object/), as in a series of images used to 'fake' a 3d object by swapping different renderings of the same object based on the camera position/rotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papervision3D is a set of custom classes. A 'sprite' in papervision is a display object. The following code will create a new copy of the Sprite class.

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

You can extend the sprite in the follow way:

```
package {
   import flash.display.Sprite;

   public class extendedSprite extends Sprite{

   }
}
```

The BasicView class is, in the end, an extended of the Sprite class.